# Angular2-beta 17 - manually apply Validator

Tags: validation, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

We currenty have a legacy project, that needs to be maintained until the final version implementing angular-final is deployed.

In final I can easily apply conditional `Validators` using:

```
this.myForm.controls['name'].setValidators(Validators.required)
```

Obviously the set method was not available back then, the only exposed thing was

```
validator: ValidatorFN;
```

property on `AbstractControl`.

So following this, I tried setting it by just doing:

```
this.myForm.controls['someControl'].validator(Validators.required)
```

which will unfortunately throw the following error:

```
"Cannot read property 'validationViolations' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there is no explicit setter method you can set a new validator via this.myForm.controls['someControl'].validator=

Cheers